# how to install webdriver_manager on mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from ChromeDriverManager) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32 (from ChromeDriverManager)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 23.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Collecting ChromeDriverManager
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/c6/f684eef613a867b1c6dda3e194942501820219f1042f81f5fef6dfc4fa79/chromedrivermanager-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pypiwin32 (from ChromeDriverManager)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/1b/2f292bbd742e369a100c91faa0483172cd91a1a422a6692055ac920946c5/pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from ChromeDriverManager)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywin32 (from ChromeDriverManager)